# How to label geom_bar with pecentage (position fill)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add % to the bars but having some challenges. Can anyone help?

```
ggplot(age_gender, aes(x = Q1, fill = Q2)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  theme_classic() + labs(title = "Proportion of gender by age group", x = "Age group",
                         y = "Proportion/Percentage") + scale_fill_discrete(name= "Gender")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get frequency within a group:

```
age_gender1 <-age_gender %>% 
      count(Q1, Q2) %>%
      mutate(Freq = n/sum(n))
```

To create the plot:

```
ggplot(age_gender1, aes(x=Q1, y=Freq, fill=Q2))+  
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Freq)), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))+
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(title = "Proportion of gender by age group", x = "Age group", y = "%", fill="Gender")+  
  scale_fill_discrete(name= "Gender")
```

Sample data:

```
age_gender<-structure(list(Q1 = c("18-21", "18-21", "18-21", "18-21", "18-21", 
"18-21", "18-21", "18-21", "18-21", "18-21", "18-21", "18-21", 
"22-24", "22-24", "22-24", "22-24", "22-24", "22-24", "22-24", 
"22-24", "22-24", "22-24", "22-24", "25-29", "25-29", "25-29", 
"25-29", "25-29", "30-34", "30-34", "30-34", "30-34", "30-34", 
"35-39", "35-39", "35-39", "35-39", "35-39", "35-39", "40-44", 
"40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "40-44", 
"40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "40-44", "45-49", "45-49", 
"45-49", "45-49", "45-49", "45-49", "45-49", "50-54", "50-54", 
"50-54", "50-54", "50-54", "50-54", "50-54", "50-54", "55-59", 
"55-59", "55-59", "55-59", "55-59", "55-59", "55-59", "60-69", 
"60-69", "60-69", "60-69", "60-69", "60-69", "60-69", "70+", 
"70+", "70+", "70+", "70+", "70+", "70+", "70+", "70+", "70+"
), Q2 = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -91L))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am still not seeing the % within each bar on the plot itself. Usually, geom_text is used to label the bars but I am having challenges with that.

Comment: @Rizzle is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Where did you learn ggplot2? Could you provide me with some source material to assist me with my studies? I find most material out there that I have come across are not very comprehensive.

Comment: @Rizzle Glad the code worked for you. You must read and act upon this short post https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Otherwise, this link helped me learn R: https://ourcodingclub.github.io/